# activity becomes fullscreen when toolbar is transparent

Tags: android

I am trying to use a transparent toolbar in my app. However, when I set my toolbar as transparent the activity expands to fullscreen height and some content overlaps with my toolbar.

[image]

Here is the layout code for the activity:

app_bar_main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aaaaa.www.aaaaaaaaa" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml :

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Change relative layout of app_bar_main.xml with LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your relative layout xml

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: This solves the problem but I still don't know why the layout is expanding.

Comment: i think its because of this: <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a RelativeLayout as parent container in app_bar_main.xml where all children will occupy the entire view if set to match parent. You can change it to LinearLayout with vertical mode where Android will arrange the children one by one in vertical direction without overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
```